# How do you get the raw integer bit pattern back from a Swift unsafe pointer?

Tags: swift

You can construct an `UnsafePointer` from an integer, like:

```
let ptr = UnsafePointer<Void>(bitPattern: 123)
```

But how do you get that integer bit pattern (in this case, 123) back from the pointer?

**Why would you do this?**

(Added in response to some comments, which suggested I'm not using pointers correctly.)

This is not something you normally do, and the above pointer is not really a pointer to anything. If the program dereferenced it, it would crash.

Some low level C APIs use `void *` to refer to some arbitrary data. It's C's version of generic types. For example, imagine a stack data structure in C, with an API like

```
Stack *create_stack();
void stack_push(Stack *stack, void *element);
void *stack_pop(Stack *stack);
```

Usually you'd pass pointers to heap allocated data, but lets say you just want a stack of 64 bit integers, and you know that pointers on your system are 64 bits.  You could store the integers directly in your stack, and avoid heap allocation...

```
Stack *myStack = create_stack();
long elt = 123;
stack_push(myStack, (void*)elt);
...
elt = (long)stack_pop(myStack);
```

I'm dealing with an API like this, but more complex (for polygon tesselation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer on another forum. Use `unsafeBitCast`:

```
let ptr = UnsafePointer<Void>(bitPattern: 123)
let x: Int64 = unsafeBitCast(ptr, Int64.self)
// x == 123
```

Answer (score 5):

Although `unsafeBitCast` works, the more natural Swift solution is

```swift
let ptr = UnsafePointer<Void>(bitPattern: 123)
let x = Int(bitPattern: ptr)
```

(Note that `Int` is the same size as a pointer on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.)

Both `Int` and `UInt` have `bitPattern:` initializers for several pointer types:

- `UnsafePointer<_>?`
- `UnsafeRawPointer?`
- `UnsafeMutablePointer<_>?`
- `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`
- `OpaquePointer?`
- `ObjectIdentifier`

And all of those pointer types except `ObjectIdentifier` have their own `bitPattern:` initializers for both `Int` and `UInt`.

An example where you might need this sort of conversion is the [`dlsym`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/dlsym.3.html) function, which has this C declaration:

```c
extern void * dlsym(void * __handle, const char * __symbol);
```

Swift imports it like this:

```swift
public func dlsym(
  _ __handle: UnsafeMutableRawPointer!,
  _ __symbol: UnsafePointer<CChar>!
) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer!
```

For the `handle` argument, you can pass a handle returned by `dlopen`, or you can pass one of several magic constants. The magic constants are defined like this in C:

```c
#define RTLD_NEXT   ((void *) -1)   /* Search subsequent objects. */
#define RTLD_DEFAULT    ((void *) -2)   /* Use default search algorithm. */
#define RTLD_SELF   ((void *) -3)   /* Search this and subsequent objects (Mac OS X 10.5 and later) */
#define RTLD_MAIN_ONLY  ((void *) -5)   /* Search main executable only (Mac OS X 10.5 and later) */
```

But Swift doesn't import these constants. If you want to use one of them in Swift, you can use `UnsafeMutableRawPointer(bitPattern:)` to create the necessary constant:

```
fileprivate let RTLD_DEFAULT = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(bitPattern: -2)
let mySym = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "mySym")
```